# Limits of functions involving exponentials and logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

I am having problem in solving this indetermination.
**$\lim_{x\to 0}  \dfrac{(e^x+3x-1)}{(e^{2x}-1)}$**

I tried to do two limits $\dfrac {(e^x+3x-1)}{x}$ times $\dfrac {x}{(e^{2x}-1)}$
but I don't know how to get rid of $e^{\dfrac y3}$ in the first limit after doing the first variable exchange.

Could you guys give a hint, please?
Thank you

Comment: L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Taylor series ?

Comment: $${e^x+3x-1\over e^{2x}-1}={1\over e^x+1}\left(1+3{x\over e^x-1}\right)\to{1\over2}\left(1+{3\over 1}\right)=\ldots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1$.  Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{e^{2x}-1}=\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac12$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x+3x-1}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x+\frac{3x}x=1+3=4$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to0}  {e^x+3x-1\over e^{2x}-1}=4\times\frac12=2$$

Comment: Now, I can do. :) I just have to separate the (3x)/x
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, we  can apply l'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\space\frac{e^x+3x-1}{e^{2x}-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\space\frac{e^x+3}{2e^{2x}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\space\frac{e^x+3}{e^{2x}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{e^0+3}{e^{2\cdot0}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1+3}{1}=2$$